# How to translate "Anstrich" in draw/wrinting context into English?

Tags: translation, single-word-request, meaning-in-context, german-to-english

The word "Anstrich" is used in different contexts. Here I'm refering to a stroke beginning the sketch of a character. This stroke is not part of the character but often used when it comes to handwriting. What word is used express "Anstrich" in that context?

**Note**
As mentioned by splattne: without context the most common meaning of the word is "paint/paintwork/coat of paint" (noun).

Comment: I vote to close, since you know the german meaning, but search for an english word, which is off topic, imho. I used this post [on meta as an example](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/136/are-translation-requests-from-german-allowed-sind-fragen-nach-ubersetungen-a/244#244)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with "upstroke". But use the terms with some caution: A quick Google search shows that this term is indeed used, but that some writers feel the need to specify that it's not any kind of stroke heading upwards, but indeed the stroke at the very beginning of a word or letter. Some examples:

- [A tutorial on cursive handwriting](http://www.2020site.org/writing/Free-Cursive-Writing-Worksheets-Uppercase.html) writes: "[...] Letters that start with an upstroke [...]"
- [A discussion about the usefulness of cursive](http://www.wisegeek.com/should-people-still-use-cursive-writing.htm)writes: "[...] the letter a has an upstroke before the body of the letter [...]"

Others again simply write "upstroke" without feeling the need to specify that it is actually 
the "Anstrich" which is being referred to.

Edit: *"Upstroke" and "downstroke" have other related meanings as well; it is used in conducting, guitar playing and painting as well.*

Comment: _upstroke_ sounds good - can you provide a source for _downstroke_ in that context?

Comment: @mbx: You're right "downstroke" is not used specifically for the _first_ stroke of a word or letter. I'll correct it. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 4):

I think

> upstroke

is the right word in this context. Dictionary: [here](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/anstrich).

In [this glossary page](http://www.robaweb.de/gdm/inhalt/GlossarBegriffe/Aufstrich.html) there's this definition of *Aufstrich (= Anstrich)*:

> Beim Schreibvorgang eine nach oben gezogene Linie eines Buchstabens.

---

*Note: without context the most common meaning of the word is "paint/paintwork/coat of paint" (noun).*